# which soundpack does these sfx comes from?

Tags: sound, sound-libraries, samples

I've heard some samples from a video game and I've noticed them in many TV shows / other videogames.

So I think they are part of a widely used soundpack.

- Did you recognize the soundpack, if so, which one is it ?
- Can I use them into my own music production / games ? 
  (after paying royalties, of course)

Here are the samples:

- http://www.filedropper.com/rotdrop
- http://www.filedropper.com/magiceffect

Answer (score 1):

Probably something like this https://www.sound-ideas.com/Product/42/General-Series-6000 .

Comment: Yeah, it seems to be one of these. But I didn't though they were so expensive. at least it satisfied my curiosity, thanks you so much :)